# Is it possible to implicitly add object fields to XML using XStream?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xstream

I have to convert a sorted set of objects of type **Organization** to an XML file.
The said type contains, along with primitive types and String objects, other reference type objects.

Here are the fields of **Organization**:

```
String orgName;
double capital;
Individual generalDirector;
Investor investor;
```

Next comes **Investor**:

```
Individual name;
double sharesPercentage;
```

And finally **Individual**:

```
String firstName;
String lastName;
```

As you can see, both **Organization** and **Investor** contain references to objects of type **Individual**.

Problem is, I need both *firstName* and *lastName* displayed in XML for the **Organization** objects, and only *lastName* for the **Investor** objects, so omitting *firstName* completely wouldn't work.

I also want to omit the <'generalDirector'> and <'investor'> tags from the output, but leave their content in separate tags, as in:

```
    <organization>
        <orgName>Dummy Solutions</orgName>
        <capital>50000</capital>
        <dirFirstName>Jacob</dirFirstName>
        <dirLastName>Smith</dirLastName>
        <investor>
            <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
            <sharePercentage>5.13</sharePercentage>
        </investor>
    </organization>
```

But XStream converts it in the following way:

```
  <organization>
      <orgName>Dummy Solutions</orgName>
      <generalDirector>
          <firstName>Jacob</firstName>
          <lastName>Smith</lastName>
      </generalDirector>
      <capital>50000</capital>
      <investor>
          <name>
              <firstName>NotSpecified</firstName>
              <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
          </name>
          <sharesPercentage>5.13</sharesPercentage>
      </investor>
  </organization>
```

How can I get rid of the *generalDirector* and Investor's *name* tags without removing their content? I know there is a way to do it for Collections, but what about reference object fields?
  And is there a way to display both **firstName** and **lastName** for **Individual** contained in Organization, but not in **Investor**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is impossible to do it quite the way I originally imagined.

However, the solution to my problem comes in form of a [custom Converter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xstream/xstream_custom_converter.htm), which implements the Converter interface from XStream package. Inside such a converter one can specify a way to serialize/deserialize a particular class of objects.

Upon doing that the solution is as easy as registering the specified converter in the current XStream instance, like so:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.registerConverter(new YourCustomConverter());
```